# How can I convert from "System.Collections.GenericList<Artikel>" to "Artikel"?

Tags: c#

```
   public List<Racun> IzdaniRacun { get; }
    public List<Artikel> ZalogaArtiklov { get; }
    public List<RezerviranArtikel> ZalogaRezerviraniArtiklov { get; }

    public Lekarna(List<Racun> izdaniRacuniList, List<Artikel> zalogaArtiklov, List<RezerviranArtikel> zalogaRezerviraniArtiklovList)
    {
        IzdaniRacun = izdaniRacuniList;
        ZalogaArtiklov = zalogaArtiklov;
        ZalogaRezerviraniArtiklov = zalogaRezerviraniArtiklovList;
    }

    //void rezervirajArtikel(Artikel artikel, Oseba oseba), ki artikel premakne iz zaloge in ga uvrsti na seznam rezerviranih artiklov
    public void rezervirajArtikel(Artikel artikel, Oseba oseba)
    {
        List<Artikel> selected = ZalogaArtiklov.Where(a => a.Id == artikel.Id).ToList();
        selected.ForEach(item => ZalogaArtiklov.Remove(item));

        ZalogaRezerviraniArtiklov.AddRange(new RezerviranArtikel(selected, oseba));

        foreach (Artikel a in ZalogaArtiklov)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(a);
        }

        foreach (RezerviranArtikel a in ZalogaRezerviraniArtiklov)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(a);
        }
    }
```

**RezerviranArtikel Class**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class RezerviranArtikel 
{
    // Pripravite razred RezerviranArtikel, ki vsebuje artikel in osebo za katero je artikel rezerviran.
    public Artikel Artikel { get; }
    public Oseba Oseba { get; }

    public RezerviranArtikel(Artikel artikel, Oseba oseba)
    {
        Artikel = Artikel;
        Oseba = oseba;
    }
}
```

I basically have to move the item from one list (Article) to another, (ReservedArticle) by removing item from one list and adding it to the oher one.

But I am having a problem with fixing this error becuase I can not conver from List to an object named "Artikel". Do you have any suggestions on how to fix that error?

**Error:    CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'Artikel'**

on this line of code:

```
ZalogaRezerviraniArtiklov.AddRange(new RezerviranArtikel(selected, oseba));
```

Comment: Please post code as text, not as image. How is this related to "Objective C"?

Comment: Sorry I meant Object oriented programming... and I replaced the image with code.

Comment: Do you have any error?

Comment: @MaikHasler Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1503 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Artikel>' to 'Artikel'

Comment: Please share your `RezerviranArtikel` class to check the constructor code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use :

```
ZalogaRezerviraniArtiklov.AddRange(selected.Select(article => new RezerviranArtikel(article, oseba));
```

because you want to convert each `Artikel` in `selected` list to `RezerviranArtikel`, not just one element.

Answer (score 2):

As you are using `.AddRange` method then it looks like you want to add a collection of `RezerviranArtikel`. So your code will look like this:

```
ZalogaRezerviraniArtiklov.AddRange(selected.Select(selectedArticle => new 
    RezerviranArtikel(selectedArticle, oseba));
```

Comment: Shouldn't `ZalogaRezerviraniArtiklov.AddRange(new List<RezerviranArtikel> {new RezerviranArtikel(...) });` ?

Or `ZalogaRezerviraniArtiklov.Add(new RezerviranArtikel(...));`

Comment: That does not solve the issue of my error...

Comment: @AquaBalls please, see my updated answer

Comment: @StepUp what's the point of using AddRange and creating a list when you can just call Add for a single element ? Also it's obvious he wanted to add all elements he removed from the other list so .First will not do what he wants, he can either remove the lists or use single values.

Comment: @RafaelMunitić yeah, you are right! I was in hurry and wrote from phone and OP shown constructor of  `RezerviranArtikel`. You already answered, so I just edited my reply.